# proxy http request to nats request

Tags: http, microservices, devops, api-gateway, nats.io

We are going to implement one of our projects as a microservice due to having many large parts
Our microservices are in go, nodejs languages and we use kong for api gateway
Communication between microservices is through nats
We use nestjs and adonisjs frameworks on the server side and vuejs on the front side

The connection of the website and the admin panel with the server is through socket and rest api, and these requests are first managed by kong.
Now, when an http request enters the server, we can send the request to the relevant microservice in two ways

1. Directly send the http request to the relevant microservice
2. After entering the server, send the http request to nats through request/reply through a piece of golang code and return the return value to the user again through http.

[image]
In the picture above, the user's request is sent to the relevant microservice after passing the api gateway, and the relevant microservice receives information from other microservices through nats from other microservices if needed.

[image]
In this case, after entering the server, the user's http requests are converted to nats through a micro framework and sent to nats.

**Which of the above methods is better?**

Comment: For the first case, you need some kind of communication between the api-gateway and the services. So the services need to have for example rest-api (to communicate with the api-gateway) and also nats subscribe/publish subjects.
For the second case the just need to have nats subscribe/publish subjects. Imo I would go with 2nd option. But since this was asked 5 months ago :D could you tell use what you chose